# Superstitious hotel elevator

Tags: code-golf, math, number, sequence

## Description

Here's a very superstitious hotel elevator in Shanghai:

[image]

It avoids the number 13, because thirteen is unlucky in the Western world, and it avoids the digit 4, because four is unlucky in parts of Asia. What if this hotel was taller?

Read a positive even integer `n` from STDIN, representing the number of floors, and print what the button layout would look like to STDOUT: `-1`, followed by the next `n-1` positive integers that aren't equal to 13 and don't contain digit 4. Arrange these numbers in two columns such as in the above image: print two floor numbers per line, separated by a horizontal tab, so that reading the lines in reverse order from left-to-right yields the sequence in ascending order. (You may optionally print a trailing newline character, too.)

## Test cases

For the input `14`, output should be as in the above image:

```
15  16
11  12
9   10
7   8
5   6
2   3
-1  1
```

where the whitespace in each line is a single horizontal tab character.

For the input `2`, you should print `-1  1`.

For the input `100`, you should print:

```
120 121
118 119
116 117
113 115
111 112
109 110
107 108
105 106
102 103
100 101
98  99
96  97
93  95
91  92
89  90
87  88
85  86
82  83
80  81
78  79
76  77
73  75
71  72
69  70
67  68
65  66
62  63
60  61
58  59
56  57
53  55
51  52
39  50
37  38
35  36
32  33
30  31
28  29
26  27
23  25
21  22
19  20
17  18
15  16
11  12
9   10
7   8
5   6
2   3
-1  1
```

## Goal

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). Shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: Wouldn't they also avoid `n13`?

Comment: I don't think anyone considers e.g. `6138` an unlucky number over here. Either way, you should print integers that contain `13` but aren't equal to it.

Comment: Okay, cool! (filler)

Comment: @Mauris 6138, maybe not, but 113? I think the key would be whether you _say_ "thirteen" when you read the number out loud.

Comment: Also, how tall can the hotel get? What about floor 666 (which occurs at 456 floors in the "standard" version, and 449 in the more aggressively 13-avoiding version)

Comment: @Random832 What you suggest are effectively arbitrary changes to the spec.  The PPCG etiquette discourages such changes after answers have been given, especially if existing answers are effectively invalidated, which they would be in this case

Comment: FWIW, 4 isn't unlucky. 4 just sounds very similar to "die" or "death" in the various chinese dialects/languages.

Comment: Is it acceptable if the numbers within each column are right-aligned? I guess yes, because the challenge doesn't say anything about it, but just to double check. Also, will the inohut number always be even? What if it's odd?

Comment: @Mauris is there a limit of the number of floors we have to be able to process? Are the chinese going to build a space elevator?

Comment: @Random832, I'm not changing the spec. Only avoid 13 or numbers containing 4.

Comment: @ThisNameBetterBeAvailable: If your program is limited by something like integer overflow, that's fine, but if your language of choice handles arbitrary-precision integer arithmetic, your code should *theoretically* work for any input size.

Comment: @LuisMendo I'm not sure what you mean: I assume you are working in some programming language that can format the output for you and print a nice two-column table. In the interest of fairness, I would like everyone's output to be *exactly* of the form `15\t16\n12\t11\n...`, so what you write would not be allowed.

Comment: @slebetman: Well, yes, that's *why* 4 is unlucky. It's still superstition, whatever the origin is! But that's getting a bit off-topic.

Comment: @Mauris my submission can calculate just enough floors to get around the earth, but it can't reach the moon... yet. Time to bring out the ULL's

Comment: Wait! Counting the buttons I see that hotel has exactly 13 floors (excluding the basement.) There's no way I'm staying  *there!*

Comment: And apparently, zero is unlucky somewhere as well. USA, I think.

Comment: How should odd inputs be treated?

Comment: @BlackOwlKai The problem says, “Read a positive even integer `n` from STDIN”… Here on PPCG, that means you can assume the output is indeed a positive even integer. Your solution may handle invalid inputs (odd, negative, zero…) in whatever way it likes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Pyth, 27 bytes

```
jjLC9_c+_1.f&!@\4`ZnZ13tQ)2
```

[Try it online here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jjLC9_c%2B_1.f%26%21%40%5C4%60ZnZ13tQ%292&input=100&debug=0).

Gets `.f`irst `Q-1` numbers that match the filter `!=13` and `4` isn't in the string representation of the number. Then it prepends `-1` , chops in half, joins each by tabs(`C9`) and joins by newlines.

Answer (score 19):

## Bash + common utils, 51

```bash
seq 9$1|sed 13d\;/4/d\;1i-1|rs 0 2|sed $[$1/2]q|tac
```

- `seq` generates ascending integers from 1 to N with an extra 9 digit in front - more than enough for 64bit integer input
- `sed` filters out the unlucky floors and inserts `-1` before line 1
- `rs` reshapes into two tab-separated columns
- `sed` stops after N/2 lines
- `tac` reverses output line order

Comment: I can shave 5 bytes for you - replace the `sed $[$1/2]q` after `rs` with `sed $1q` before it.  I think that makes it POSIX-shell compatible, too.

Comment: Eventually, the preceding `1` won't be enough to compensate for passing only 0.9^n of the inputs through (numbers not containing `4` get sparser and sparser as the number of digits increases).  But once you have more than a few hundred million floors in your hotel, you probably have other problems, such as keeping the plumbing working, and organising staff rotas.

Comment: @TobySpeight you might have a space elevator too :)

Comment: @TobySpeight Even with the max signed 64bit integer as input (9223372036854775807), simply prefixing a 1 is (just about) enough - at least with my rudimentary base 9 calculation.  The rest of the answer is limited to this range anyway due to the shell `$[]` arithmetic.  I think this is a reasonable limitation in the absence of explicit mention of arbitrary precision arithmetic in the question.  Regardless, I'm now prefixing a `9` instead of  `1`, just to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 10):

## JavaScript ES6, <s>236</s> <s>234</s> <s>233</s> <s>210</s> <s>195</s> 188 bytes

Saved a whole bunch 'a bytes thanks to usandfriends!

Uses the `function*` for generators. Probably a shorter way to do this, but it was fun. *Way* fun. I'll bet some golfing can be done. Those weird whitespace things are tabs.

```
z=prompt(i=x=0,l=[]);y=(function*(){while(i<z-x)yield(i?(/4/.test(i)||i==13?--x&&".":i):-1)+(0*++i)})();while(a=y.next().value)+a&&l.push(a);l.join`    `.match(/-?\d+  \d+/g).reverse().join`
`
```

Comment: `z=+prompt(i=x=0,l=[]);` ==> `z=prompt(i=x=0,l=[]);` (-1 byte)

Comment: @usandfriends Thank you! I forgot about automatic type conversion.

Comment: `.join` with tab and replace space in `/-?\d+ \d+/g` with tab, remove `.map(x=>x.replace(/ /,"\t"))` (should save 23 bytes)

Comment: @usandfriends And thanks again!

Comment: For some reason, I seem to be getting a [byte count of 210](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter#z%3Dprompt%28i%3Dx%3D0%2Cl%3D%5B%5D%29%3By%3D%28function%2a%28%29%7Bwhile%28i%3Cz-x%29yield%28i%3F%28%28i%2B%22%22%29.search%284%29%2B1%7C%7Ci%3D%3D13%3F--x%26%26%22.%22%3Ai%29%3A-1%29%2B%280%2a%2B%2Bi%29%7D%29%28%29%3Bwhile%28a%3Dy.next%28%29.value%29l.push%28a%29%3Bl.filter%28x%3D%3Ex!%3D%22.0%22%29.join%60%09%60.match%28%2F-%3F%5Cd%2B%09%5Cd%2B%2Fg%29.reverse%28%29.join%60%0A%60).

Comment: @usandfriends That's weird, The length is 207 on my console...

Comment: Shows `210` when I use [this](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter), [this](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/4944/39042), and `wc -c`. Just curious, what command do you use to check file size?

Comment: `.filter(x=>x!=".0")` ==> `.filter(x=>+x)`, (-5 bytes)

Comment: ^ _Scratch that_, just remove the whole `.filter(..)` part! Try `l.push(a);` ==> `+a&&l.push(a);` (-15 bytes)

Comment: @usandfriends Thank you so much for you golfs! :D

Answer (score 7):

## C, 282 Bytes

```
int main(int r,char*v[]){int c=atoi(v[1]),a[c],b,E=1E9,g,i,t,o=t=g=(E)-2;while(i++<c){while(t>0){r=t%10;t=t/10;if(r==4||g==(E)+13||g<=o||g==E)t=++g;}a[i-1]=o=t=g;}for(c-=3;c>=0;c-=2){printf("%d\t",a[c+1]-E);printf("%d\n",a[c+2]-E);}printf("%d\t",a[0]-E);if(i%2)printf("%d",a[1]-E);}
```

#### Formatted :

```
int main ( int r , char * v[] ) {
    int c = atoi ( v[ 1 ] ) , a[c] , b , E = 1E9 , g , i , t , o = t = g = ( E ) - 2;
    while ( i ++ < c ) {
        while ( t > 0 ) {
            r = t % 10;
            t = t / 10;
            if ( r == 4 || g == ( E ) + 13 || g <= o || g == E )t = ++ g;
        }
        a[ i - 1 ] = o = t = g;
    }
    for ( c -= 3 ; c >= 0 ; c -= 2 ) {
        printf ( "%d\t" , a[ c + 1 ] - E );
        printf ( "%d\n" , a[ c + 2 ] - E );
    }
    printf ( "%d\t" , a[ 0 ] - E );
    if ( i % 2 )printf ( "%d" , a[ 1 ] - E );
}
```

**Features :**

It can compute up to 2095984 floors, if each floor is `19.5m` high (incl. ceiling) then this building is long enough to be wrapped around the equator! `2095984*19.5=40871688m=~40000km=one 'lap' around the planet`.

Comment: Nice answer, but your geography's a bit off. The distance from the equator to the north pole is 10000km by definition https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metre which means the circumference of the equator is a little over 40000km.

Comment: Nice comment, but your definition of the metre is a bit outdated. ;-)

Comment: @steveverrill i just used the first number i got off google, i'll update the calculation.

Comment: You can save a few bytes by dropping "int" from main. Are braces around E really necessary? First `while` can be converted to `for` and this allows you to drop some curly braces. `t/=10` is a byte shorter than `t=t/10`. Add 1 to c in you `for` loop to save a couple bytes -> `a[c+1]` becomes `a[c]`, while all other numbers have the same length. I'd also combine two `printf`s in the loop together, and dropped curly braces again.

Comment: I think your definition of "floor height" might be a bit off - a typical floor is about 3m tall, not 19.5m tall.

Comment: @aragaer yes, you're right about the `int`, `t/=10` and everything.
Thank you.

Comment: @nneonneo `if each floor is 19.5m`, i didn´t say this was typical.
I'll suggest you look at my edits.

Answer (score 6):

## Julia, <s>134</s> 132 bytes

```
x=[-1;filter(i->i!=13&&'4'∉"$i",1:2(n=parse(readline())))][1:n]
for i=2:2:endof(x) println(join((r=reverse)(r(x)[i-1:i]),"  "))end
```

That funny whitespace in there is a literal tab. As Conor O'Brien noted, this is a byte shorter than doing `\t`.

Ungolfed:

```
# Read an integer from STDIN
n = parse(readline())

# Generate all numbers from 1 to 2n, exclude 0, 13, and all numbers containing 4,
# prepend -1, then take the first n
x = [-1; filter(i -> i != 13 && '4' ∉ "$i", 1:2n)][1:n]

# Loop over pairs, print tab-separated
for i = 2:2:endof(x)
    println(join(reverse(reverse(x)[i-1:i]), "  "))
end
```

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript, 116 <s>122</s>

**Edit** Saved 6 bytes thx @Neil

Simple array solution - not even using ES6

Try with any browser

```js
/* test */ console.log=function(x){ O.innerHTML+=x+'\n'; }

n=prompt();for(r=[-1],v=1;n;v++)v!=13&!/4/.test(v)&&--n&&r.push(v);for(;r[0];)console.log(a=r.pop(b=r.pop())+'\t'+b)
```

```html
<pre id=O></pre>
```

Comment: You can save 6 bytes by using `!/4/.test(v)`.

Comment: You could save a single byte with `' '` instead of `'\t'` (literal tab)

Answer (score 6):

### Python 2, <s>120</s> 110 bytes

```python
N=input()
n=['-1']+[`i`for i in range(N*2)if i!=13and'4'not in`i`][1:N]
while n:x=n.pop();print n.pop()+'\t'+x
```

Comment: I think you can use `i-13` instead of `i!=13`

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 94 bytes

```python
n=input();c=-1;s=''
while n:
 if('4'in`c`)==0!=c!=13:n-=1;s=(n%2*'%d	%%d\n'+s)%c
 c+=1
print s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcrBCoMwDADQ8/oV9RDSKkLrPCn5kx2EqBgYWbGVsa@v7J1f@pXjo0OtSqLpKs7PTH2cMyGa7yHvzepkrOwORxRdePFEoSFuKD4n7elfncLQIqwPgPWl2GUPbCx3FE06RYvNtcYQbg)

There's a tab character in the string that SE doesn't render (thanks to Sp3000 for suggested to use it, saving a byte).

Tests floors `c` starting from floor `-1` until the quota `n` of floors is reached. For each floor, tests that it doesn't contain a `4` nor equals `0` or `13`. If so, prepends it to the elevator string `s` and decrements the quota `n`.

A trick with string formatting is used to get the two floors per column to appear in the proper order when prepended. Each new line is prepared as `'%d\t%%d\n'`, so that when two floors are substituted in order, the first is on the left and the second is on the right. For example,

```python
('%d\t%%d\n'%2)%3 == ('2\t%d\n')%3 == '2\t3\n'
```

Comment: Pretty cool, but it's actually [96 bytes](https://tio.run/##FcpBCsIwEAXQfU6RLsIk1kITXbXMTVwURqUD8g1NRHr6VDdv9fJe1zdSa2BF/lQfZuEhzoWJzHfV18NiMlafnq6kWGQJzGPH0nG8TBj4Xz1cOpG736r7AepLcGKs9BxN3hTVlnNraTwA "Python 2 – Try It Online"). Probably remove the trailing comma?

Comment: @movatica Good catch on the trailing comma, since the challenge specifies trailing newline is OK. The 1 byte difference was because the SE code block can't display tabs, so I put in a `\t`. Ah, the days before TIO existed.

Answer (score 5):

## Ruby 2.3, <s>84</s> 83 characters

(82 characters code + 1 characters command line option)

```ruby
puts (["-1",*?1..?1+$_].grep_v(/^13$|4/)[0..$_.to_i]*?\t).scan(/\S+\t\d+/).reverse
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ ruby -ne 'puts (["-1",*?1..?1+$_].grep_v(/^13$|4/)[0..$_.to_i]*?\t).scan(/\S+\t\d+/).reverse' <<< '14'
15      16
11      12
9       10
7       8
5       6
2       3
-1      1
```

### Ruby, <s>93</s> 92 characters

(91 characters code + 1 character command line option)

```ruby
puts ([-1,*1..2*n=$_.to_i].reject{|i|i==13||i.to_s[?4]}[0..n]*?\t).scan(/\S+\t\d+/).reverse
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ ruby -ne 'puts ([-1,*1..2*n=$_.to_i].reject{|i|i==13||i.to_s[?4]}[0..n]*?\t).scan(/\S+\t\d+/).reverse' <<< '14'
15      16
11      12
9       10
7       8
5       6
2       3
-1      1
```

Answer (score 5):

## C#, 296 bytes

```
namespace System.Collections.Generic{using Linq;class X{static void Main(){var a=new List<int>();var b=new List<int>();for(int i=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()),j=-2;i>0;)if(++j!=13&&j!=0&&!(j+"").Contains("4"))(i--%2<1?a:b).Insert(0,j);Console.Write(string.Join("\n",a.Zip(b,(x,y)=>x+"\t"+y)));}}}
```

Ungolfed:

```
namespace System.Collections.Generic
{
    using Linq;
    class X
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var a = new List<int>();
            var b = new List<int>();
            for (int i = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()), j = -2; i > 0;)
                if (++j != 13 && j != 0 && !(j + "").Contains("4"))
                    (i-- % 2 < 1 ? a : b).Insert(0, j);
            Console.Write(string.Join("\n", a.Zip(b, (x, y) => x + "\t" + y)));
        }
    }
}
```

Golfing tricks used:

- *i* (the running counter) and *j* (the current number under consideration) are decremented/incremented, respectively, inside the expression in the loop body instead of the for statement as is normal
- `j+""` instead of `j.ToString()`
- Place everything inside `namespace System.Collections.Generic` not only so that we can access `List<T>`, but also implicitly use the namespace `System` without further qualification
- Place the `using` inside the namespace so that we can write `using Linq;` instead of `using System.Linq;`
- `.Insert(0,j)` is shorter than using `.Add(j)` and later applying `.Reverse()`

It is unfortunate that the `using Linq;` is necessary, since it is needed only for `.Zip`, but writing it as `Linq.Enumerable.Zip()` is longer.

Answer (score 4):

## Lua, 169 Bytes

```
t={-1}i=1 repeat if(i..""):find("4")or i==13 then else table.insert(t,i)end i=i+1 until #t==arg[1] for i=#t%2==0 and#t-1 or#t,1,-2 do print(t[i],t[i+1]and t[i+1]or"")end
```

Fairly straight forward, we first assemble a table filled with all the button values. Then we iterate through it backwards, printing two values at a time, or nothing if the second value does not exist.

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, 105 bytes

```
StringRiffle[Reverse[Select[Range[2#]-2,#!=13&&#!=0&&DigitCount[#,10,4]<1&][[;;#]]~Partition~2],"
","\t"]&
```

Replace the `\t` with an actual tab character.

Answer (score 4):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 105 bytes

```
,Ll?,Lbb:1{h_.|[L:I]hhH,I+1=J((13;J:Zm4),L:J:1&.;Lb:J:1&:[J]c.)}:[1:-1]c{_|hJ,?bhw,[9:J]:"~c~w
"w,?bb:2&}
```

Would have been a lot shorter with CLPFD support, here I have to iteratively try integers in the first sub-predicate.

The new line before `"w,?bb:2&}` is mandatory, this is the new line that is printed between every row.

Comment: Nice! One question: Why not make *all* integer arithmetic in Brachylog use CLP(FD) constraints automatically? This would be a natural logical extension.

Comment: @mat because I'm lazy and I didn't. But I should!

Comment: That would be awesome! Built-in implicit CLP(FD) constraints for all integer arithmetic! Pave the future of declarative programming! "And it must seem blessedness to you to impress your hand on millennia as on wax. Blessedness to write on the will of millennia as on bronze--harder than bronze, nobler than bronze. Only the noblest is altogether hard."

Comment: @mat Could you join me in [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34284/brachylog) to discuss this? I need advice from someone obviously more experienced with Prolog than me.

Answer (score 3):

### C#, <strike>277</strike> 343

```
using System;using System.Collections.Generic;static void f(int v){List<int>a=new List<int>();List<int>b=new List<int>();int s=1;for(int i=-1;i<v-1;i++){if(i==13||i.ToString().Contains("4")||i==0){ v++;continue;}if(s==1){s=2;a.Add(i);}else{s=1;b.Add(i);}}a.Reverse();b.Reverse();int l=0;foreach(int y in a){Console.WriteLine(y+" "+b[l]);l++;}}
```

This is as a function only. I'm new to C#. Increase was to make valid for 40-49, and for including `using`s

Ungolfed, as a complete running program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class P {
    static void Main()
    {
        List<int> a = new List<int>();
        List<int> b = new List<int>();
        int v = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int s = 1;
        for (int i = -1; i < v - 1; i++)
        {
            if (i == 13 || i.ToString().Contains("4") || i == 0)
            {
                v++;
                continue;
            }
            if (s == 1)
            {
                s = 2;
                a.Add(i);
            }
            else {
                s = 1;
                b.Add(i);
            }
        }
        a.Reverse();
        b.Reverse();
        int l = 0;
        foreach (int y in a)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(y + " " + b[l]);
            l++;
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Explained

I create two lists, and alternate between pushing to them, reverse them, loop through one, and grab the other by index.

Comment: I don't know much about C# but can't you replace `if(s==1)` by `if(s)` (automatic cast from int to boolean?)

Comment: Nah, because the else is for s == 2, although I could make the flag 0 and 1 instead of 1 and 2. I'll try that.

Answer (score 3):

### C++11, <strike>259</strike> <strike>258</strike> <strike>203</strike> <strike>202</strike> <strike>195</strike> 194 bytes

Slashed off 1 byte, thanks to Conor O'Brien's idea to use literal tab instead of `\t`.

UPD 2: slashed off 55 bytes with improved logic and comma abuse.

UPD 3: another byte off thanks to ceilingcat.

UPD 4: 7 bytes off courtesy of ceilingcat.

UPD 5: and another byte off by ceilingcat.

Happy to have all includes in place AND still beat the C and C# solutions.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
int main(){std::string o="-1    1",c,b;int n,i=2,s=2;for(std::cin>>n;s<n;o=i==14|~c.find(52)?o:(++s&1?b=c,"":b+'    '+c+'\n')+o)c=std::to_string(i++);std::cout<<o;}
```

Ungolfed:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string o = "-1 1", c, b;
    int n, i = 2, s = 2;
    for (std::cin >> n;
         s < n;
         o = i == 14 | ~c.find(52) ? o : (++s & 1 ? b = c, "" : b + '   ' + c + '\n') + o
    )
        c = std::to_string(i++);
    std::cout << o;
}
```

Comment: `iostream` includes `string`, so you can skip the second include for a big decrease in bytecount :)

Comment: @movatica Not according to cppreference.com, and compilation in VS2019 fails without it. So if it compiles somewhere else it's specific to that certain standard library implementation.

Comment: ok, seems to be a gcc thing.

Comment: [191 bytes](https://tio.run/##PY3LCoMwEADP@hVioSpJCxF7MUZ/pFB0fbBQd8XEUx@/bluFXodhBqbpNACs6wEJ7kvbFcjWzV09lv4ffQHSUPpILhhrpDh5WNfm@c4DNuFJeSqUIBv9c0iiSaU1qe55jjcVkMqStC1Is0FjVPZ8w7lHauNLmlScC2GPqmoMSM4bEXmRABFdKRKcgNkSjm/7MEYhEr1neXFFwfq1rir7AA "C++ (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

### Python 3, 155 bytes

I think listifying, reversing, and self-zipping the floor-number generator `s()` may have been too clever for its own good, but others have already done the alternative (popping two items at a time), not to mention using Python 2 which saves bytes on some key points.

```py
def s(m,n=-1):
 while m:
  if not(n in(0,13)or'4'in str(n)):yield n;m-=1
  n+=1
*f,=s(int(input()))
g=iter(f[::-1])
h=zip(g,g)
for a,b in h:print(b,'\t',a)
```

The shorter, but already-done-better alternative takes 140 bytes.

```py
def s(m,n=-1):
 while m:
  if not(n in(0,13)or'4'in str(n)):yield n;m-=1
  n+=1
*f,=s(int(input()))
while f:a=f.pop();print(f.pop(),'\t',a)
```

Comment: For the second alternative, `(0!=n!=13)!=('4'in str(n))` is 5 bytes shorter than `not(n in(0,13)or'4'in str(n))`.

Answer (score 3):

## Japt, 42 bytes

```
JoU*2 k0 kD f@!Xs f4} ¯U ã f@Yv} w ®q'    } ·
```

The four spaces should be an actual tab char. [Try it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=Sm9VKjIgazAga0QgZkAhWHMgZjR9IK9VIOMgZkBZdn0gdyCucScJfSC3&input=MTQ=)

#### How it works

```
          // Implicit: U = input integer, D = 13
JoU*2     // Create the range of integers [-1,U*2).
k0 kD     // Remove 0 and 13.
f@!Xs f4} // Filter out the items X where X.toString().match(/4/g) is not null, i.e. the numbers that contain a 4.
¯U ã      // Slice to the first U items, and generate all adjacent pairs of items.
f@Yv}     // Filter out the items where the index Y is odd. This discards every other pair.
w         // Reverse.
®q'\t}    // Join each item with tabs.
·         // Join the whole list with newlines.
          // Implicit: output last expression
```

Answer (score 3):

## Lua, 141 bytes

```
n,s=1,'-1 1'function g()repeat n=n+1 until s.find(n,4)==z and n~=13 return n end for i=4,io.read(),2 do s=g()..' '..g().."\n"..s end print(s)
```

## Ungolfed

```
n,s = 1,'-1'1' --n is the current floor number, S is the string to be printed
function g() --This function raises n to the next valid floor
    repeat --Same as while loop except it runs the following block before checking the expression
        n = n + 1 --Self-explanatory, increases n by one
    until --Checks the expression, if it is true, it breaks out of the loop
        s.find(n,4) == z --[[Strings have a member :find(X) where it finds the position of
                             X in the string (X can also be a pattern). However, calling it 
                             by .find(S,X) executes find on S with argument X. I can't 
                             directly do n:find(4) because n is a number. This is a "hack" 
                             (sort of) to cut down some bytes. Also, if X is not a string,
                             lua tries to (in this case, succeeds) cast X to a
                             string and then look for it. I check if this is equal to z
                             because z is nil (because it is undefined), and find returns
                             nil if X is not found in S.
                             TL;DR: Checks if 4 is not the last digit.]]
        and n ~= 13 --Self-explanatory, checks if n is not 13
        return n --Self-explanatory, returns n
end
for i = 4, io.read(), 2 do --[[Start at floor 3 (shows 4 because we're going by target
                               floor, not by starting floor), continue until we reach
                               floor io.read() (io.read returns user input), increment by
                               2 floors per iteration)]]
    s = g() .. ' ' .. g() .. "\n" .. s --[[Prepend the next floor, a space, the next floor,
                               and a newline to s]]
end
print(s) --Self-explanatory, output the string
```

[Try it online](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_lua_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMdlgwV2dEdFdIY0U) (you need to click 'execute' on the top and then click the terminal on the bottom before typing input; I'm looking for a better way to test lua online with stdin and stdout)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>25</s> <s>23</s> 22 bytes

-1 byte thanks to @ASCII-only

```
·Ý<0K13Kʒ4å_}s£2ôR9çý»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASsA1P9vc2FiaWX//8K3w508MEsxM0vKkjTDpV99c8KjMsO0UjnDp8O9wrv//zE0)

### Explanation

```
                           # Implicit input: integer n
·Ý<                        # Push list [-1,0,1,...,2n-1]
   0K                      # Remove 0 from [-1,0,1,...,2n-1]
     13K                   # Remove 13 from [-1,1,...,2n-1]
        ʒ4å_}              # Filter out every number containing a 4 from the list
             s£            # Pick out the n first element in the list
               2ôR         # Splice list into parts of length 2
                  9çý      # Join with tab character (ascii value 9)
                     »     # Join with newlines
```

Comment: [22?](https://tio.run/##ASsA1P9vc2FiaWX//8K3w508MEsxM0vKkjTDpV99c8KjMsO0UjnDp8O9wrv//zE0)

Comment: Ah. I knew there was a way to make that ugly `0 13ª` part a bit better. Thanks!

Comment: wait. there's no logical and in 05AB1E? O_o

Comment: If 1 is true and 0 is false then multiplication works as logical and

Comment: -1 byte by changing `ʒ4å_}` to `4мïê`. PS: based on your earlier comment: `0 13ª` could have been `¾13ª` as well.

Answer (score 2):

## Java, 333 Bytes

```
import java.util.*;interface E{static void main(String[]a){byte i=-1;Stack<Byte>s=new Stack<>();while(s.size()<Byte.valueOf(a[0])){if(i==13|i==0|String.valueOf(i).contains("4")){i++;continue;}s.add(i);i++;}if(s.size()%2!=0){System.out.println(s.pop());}while(!s.isEmpty()){int r=s.pop();int l=s.pop();System.out.println(l+"\t"+r);}}}
```

Adds allowed floor numbers to a stack then pops them back off to print them.

I played around using an IntStream, but with all the imports this one ended up being smaller.

Answer (score 2):

**Scala 147**

```
val n=io.StdIn.readInt;(-1 to 4*n).filter(i=>i!=0&&i!=13&&(!(i+"").contains(52))).take(n).reverse.grouped(2).toList.map{i=>println(i(1)+"\t"+i(0))}
```

Comment: This is obviously the Scala'd down version.

Answer (score 2):

## PowerShell, 106 <s>107</s> bytes

```powershell
$c=,-1+$(while($i+1-lt"$args"){if(++$c-notmatch'^13$|4'){$c;++$i}})
while($c){$a,$b,$c=$c;$s="$a    $b
$s"}$s
```

## Ungolfed

```
# Calculate floors:
$c=,-1 # Array with one element
  +
  $( # Result of subexpression
    while($i+1-lt"$args"){ # Uninitialized $i is 0, +1 ensures loop start from 1
      if(
        ++$c-match'^13$|4' # Expression increments uninitialized $c (i.e. start from 1)
                           # and matches resulting number to regex.
      ){
        $c;++$i # Return $c and increment $i counter 
      }
    }
  )

# Print floors:
while($c){ # Loop until no more elements in $c
  $a,$b,$c=$c # Use PS's multiple assignment feature
              # $a - first element of $c array
              # $b - second element of $c array
              # $c - the rest of elements of $c array
  $s="$a    $b
$s" # Create string with tabs and newlines,
    # literal characters are used
}
$s # Output resulting string
```

## Example

```
PS > .\Elevator.ps1 14
15  16
11  12
9   10
7   8
5   6
2   3
-1  1
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, 117 Bytes

```
n=int(input())
l=[-1]+[i for i in range(n*2)if(i!=13)*(not'4'in str(i))][1:n]
while l:x=l.pop();print(l.pop(),'\t',x)
```

Modified version of the python 2 post to fit the python 3 specification.

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell 202 bytes

```
t=(-1):[x|x<-[1..],x/=13,all (/='4')(show x)]
by2 []=[[]]
by2 [a]=[[a]]
by2 [a,b]=[[a,b]]
by2 (a:b:xs)=[a,b]:(by2 xs)
main=do
 n<-getLine
 putStr$unlines$map unwords$by2$map show$reverse$take(read n) t
```

I’am haskell beginner…

- first create the infinite list of values. (t list)
- function by2 group a list into sublists of 2 elements.
- main take the value.

  - take value elements of *t* list
  - reverse the list to have greaters elements first
  - map show function to convert int list to string list
  - group element 2 by 2 with by2 function
  - We have a list like [ ["4", "5"], ["6", "7"] ] transformed like [ "4 5", "6 7"] with *unwords* function mapped on list
  - unlines the list (each element of the list separate by '\n')
  - finish with putStrLn to write string on terminal.

Comment: You can save several bytes in defining `by2` by using a 1 character name and re-ordering: use your last line as is, then `b x = [x]` after.

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript ES6 114 bytes

```
n=>[...Array(n)].map(_=>{while(/^13$|4|^0/.test(++i));return i;},i=-2).join`    `.match(/-?\d+  \d+/g).reverse().join`\n`
```

Usage

```
f=n=>[...Array(n)].map(_=>{while(/^13$|4|^0/.test(++i));return i;},i=-2).join`  `.match(/-?\d+  \d+/g).reverse().join`\n`
```

f(100);

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 73 bytes

```
{.join("    ").say for (-1,|grep {$_-13&!/4/},1..Inf)[^$_].rotor(2).reverse}
```

Assumes an even number of floors, since the problem statement seems to assume it as well and at least one other provided solution breaks for odd numbers of floors.  Just add `,:partial` as a second argument to `rotor`, for nine more bytes, to support odd numbers of floors.

Comment: [55 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwv7q6OLFSQUklLolTJS5RqTYtv0ihJr0otUCjWlHfRL82ztBYx1BPT0szWiVe10hPT88gVkfXsPZ/moahmeZ/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 20 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ḟ13D_4Ȧµ#o-s2Ṛj€9Ọ¤Y
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASsA1P9qZWxsef//4bifMTNEXzTIpsK1I28tczLhuZpq4oKsOeG7jMKkWf//MTAw)**

#### How?

```
ḟ13D_4Ȧµ#o-s2Ṛj€9Ọ¤Y - Main Link: no arguments
        #            - start at n=0 and collect the first INPUT values which are truthy under:
       µ             -   the monad (i.e. f(n)):        e.g.:    0      3      4      13     42        813
ḟ13                  -     filter out thirteens                 [0]    [3]    [4]    []     [42]      [813]
   D                 -     convert to decimal lists             [[0]]  [[3]]  [[4]]  []     [[4,2]]   [[8,1,3]]
    _4               -     subtract four (vectorises)           [[-4]] [[-1]] [[0]]  []     [[0,-2]]  [[4,-3,-1]
      Ȧ              -     any & all?                           1      1      0      0      0         1
         o-          - logical OR with -1 (replace floor 0 with floor -1)
           s2        - split into twos
             Ṛ       - reverse
                  ¤  - nilad followed by link(s) as a nilad:
                9    -   literal nine
                 Ọ   -   to character (a tab)
              j€     - join €ach
                   Y - join with newlines
                     - implicit print
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>151</s> 146

```
alert([for(a of Array((n=+prompt(i=0))*2).keys())if((i+=t=/4/.test(a)||a==13,!t&&a<n+i))a].reduce((a,b,j,r)=>j%2-1?(b||-1)+`  ${r[j+1]}
`+a:a,''))
```

Did this before I realized edc65 had already made a shorter one. Oh well!

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 106 bytes

```r
n=scan();x=-1:n^2;x=x[-grep(4,x)][-14][-2][n:1];cat(paste0(matrix(x,2,n/2)[2:1,],c("	","\n"),collapse=""))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcZBCgMhDADAc7@RUwKRVvHk4kusBREphW0q6iG/t3sZZuwtcdYiSIdGY4O83BVN5j1aR89KORnrL1xOEmw@alnYy1ztgd@yxkdR2bHcHSUXLGeuCDdgeAoQ1995lj5bBCDa1u8/)

Explanation: it starts with the vector of floors from \$-1\$ to \$n^2\$, which is more than enough in all my tests. Should that ever be insufficient, we could switch to \$n^3\$ or \$n^9\$. It then removes the unlucky floor numbers (as well as floor 0), converts to a 2-row matrix form and inverts the rows to get the numbers in correct order, then outputs in the desired format, recycling the vector `c("\t","\n")`. As [suggested](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/68869/86301) by Conor O'Brien, use a literal tab instead of `\t` for -1 byte.

```r
n=scan();                                        # read number of floors n
x=-1:n^2;                                        # initial vector of numbers
x=x[-grep(4,x)]                                  # remove floors with a 4
               [-14]                             # remove floor 13
                    [-2]                         # remove floor 0
                        [n:1];                   # keep lowest n remaining floors, highest to lowest
cat(paste0( 
  matrix(x,2,n/2)                                # split vector of floors into 2 rows
                 [2:1,],                         # take row 2 then row 1
                        c("   ","\n"),           # separate integers with alternating tabs and newlines (uses recycling)
                                    collapse=""))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 34 bytes

```apl
{⊖(⍵÷2)2⍴o/⍨~'4'∊¨⍕¨o←13~⍨¯1,⍳⍵×⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24TqR13TNB71bj283UjT6FHvlnz9R70r6tRN1B91dB1a8ah36qEV@UBlhsZ1QPFD6w11HvVuBimfDiRqgUYoGHGpa6tzpSkYmsEYBgYA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-MList::Util=pairmap -n`, 62 bytes

```perl
pairmap{say"$b	$a"}reverse((-1,grep!/^13$|4/,1..121)[0..$_-1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/78gMbMoN7GgujixUkkliVMlUam2KLUstag4VUND11AnvSi1QFE/ztBYpcZEX8dQT8/QyFAz2kBPTyVe1zBW8/9/I4N/@QUlmfl5xf91fU31DAwNgLRPZnGJlVVoSWaOLdT8/7p5AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-R`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), <s>23</s> <s>22</s> 21 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
È©DÀX«ìø4}jUJ ò Ômq9d
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVI&code=yKlEwFir7Pg0fWpVSiDyINRtcTlk&input=MTAw)

```
È©DÀX«ìø4}jUJ ò Ômq9d     :Implicit input of integer U
È                         :Function taking an integer X as argument
 ©                        :  Logical AND with
  D                       :    13
   ÀX                     :    Is not equal to X
     «                    :  Logical AND with logical NOT of
      ì                   :    Convert X to digit array
       ø4                 :    Contains 4?
         }                :End function
          jU              :Get the first U integers that return truthy
            J             :Starting with -1
              ò           :Partitions of length 2
                Ô         :Reverse
                 m        :Map
                  q       :  Join with
                   9d     :  Character at codepoint 9 (TAB)
                          :Implicit output joined with newlines
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 25 bytes

```
↔mJc9†sC2↑¹fȯ¬€4d-0-13…_1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATEAzv9odXNr///ihpRtSmM54oCgc0My4oaRwrlmyK/CrOKCrDRkLTAtMTPigKZfMf///zIw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno) `N`, \$36\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 29.63 bytes

```
1ns2*:gzt13Q&s4Aq!&kDLz0-Zy2Apre9Csj
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_abSSn1LsgqWlJWm6FjdVDPOKjbSs0qtKDI0D1YpNHAsV1bJdfKoMdKMqjRwLilItnYuzIGqhWhYsMjSBsAA)

Port of Wisław's 05AB1E answer.

##### Explanation

```python
1n        # Push -1
  s2*     # Swap and double the input
     :    # Push the range between -1 and 2*n
      g   # Filter this list by:
       zt #  Triplicate the integer       STACK:  i, i, i
13Q       #  Is it not equal to 13?       STACK:  i, i, i != 13
   &      #  Logical AND                  STACK:  i, (i and i != 13)
    s4Aq  #  Swap and check if it         STACK:  (i and i != 13), (4 in i)
          #  contains the digit 4
        ! #  Logical NOT                  STACK:  (i and i != 13), (4 not in i)
&         #  Logical AND                  STACK:  i and (i != 13) and (4 not in i)
 k        # End filter
  DL      # Duplicate and push the length
    z0-   # Subtract the input
       Zy # Remove this many elements from the back
2Ap       # Split into chunks of length 2
   r      # Reverse
    e     # Map over this list:
     9C   #  Push chr(9), a tab
       sj #  Join the list by a tab
          # N flag joins by newlines
          # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `N`, 21 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ḌĖ⁻0o13oæṘ4Ƈ}ɱ2ẇr9Cȷj
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVFMSVCOCU4QyVDNCU5NiVFMiU4MSVCQjBvMTNvJUMzJUE2JUUxJUI5JTk4NCVDNiU4NyU3RCVDOSVCMTIlRTElQkElODdyOUMlQzglQjdqJmZvb3Rlcj0maW5wdXQ9MTAwJmZsYWdzPU4=)

##### Explanation

```python
ḌĖ⁻0o13oæṘ4Ƈ}ɱ2ẇr9Cȷj  # Implicit input
ḌĖ⁻                    # Push the range [-1 .. 2*input)
   0o13o               # Remove the 0 and the 13
        æṘ4Ƈ}          # Remove anything containing 4
             ɱ         # Take the first (input) items
              2ẇ       # Split into pairs
                9Cȷj   # Join each by ASCII 9 (tab)
                       # Join on newlines
                       # Implicit output
```